# Javascript: How to determine a SVG path draw direction?

Tags: javascript, svg

I'm trying to determine a SVG path draw orientation. I'm working on something like this

```
var length = path.getTotalLength();
var horizontal = path.getPointAtLength(length/4).x - path.getPointAtLength(0).x;
var vertical = path.getPointAtLength(length/4).y - path.getPointAtLength(0).y;
```

Then do some comparisons with these values `horizontal > 0` and `vertical > 0`, but this above idea isn't, in my mind, very successful.

My question is: is there anything I can use to determine the draw direction or perhaps some built in SVG methods/options?

Thank you

Comment: A path can have multiple drawing directions. Which one are you looking for?

Comment: The overall path. I need to know if it's clockwise or counterclockwise so I can reverse it's points when I need it.

Comment: What about a path shaped like an `8`, then?

Comment: Doesn't matter the shape. We know where it starts, we know where it ends even if it's an `8` shape, there is ALWAYS the direction to draw for each point, segment and overall path. But generally I don't think I will ever encounter that kind of shape.

Comment: That CSS property / Element attribute only sets what happens with subpaths and or intersecting paths.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `Math.atan2(yDiff, xDiff)` to get the angle between the two reference points. Two visually identical shapes that go in opposite directions will have an angle difference of pi.

Be aware of the edge case where your two reference points are unluckily the same point. Not likely, especially given rounding errors, but keep it in mind in case you need this to be rock solid.

```js
var paths = document.getElementsByTagName("path");
for (var pathNum = 0; pathNum < paths.length; pathNum += 1) {
  var path = paths[pathNum];
  var message = document.createElement('p');
  message.innerHTML = "path #" + pathNum + ": angle = " + pathDir(path);
  document.body.appendChild(message);
};

function pathDir(path) {
  var length = path.getTotalLength();
  var pt14 = path.getPointAtLength(1/4 * length);
  var pt34 = path.getPointAtLength(3/4 * length);
  var angle = Math.atan2(pt14.y - pt34.y, pt14.x - pt34.x);
  return angle;
}
```

```html
<svg width="300" height="80">
  <g fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="4">
    <path d="M 10,10 C 90,10 -30,60  50,60Z"/>
    <path d="M110,10 C190,10  70,60 150,60Z"/>
    <path d="M250,60 C170,60 290,10 210,10Z"/>
  </g>
</svg>
<div></div>
```

Comment: hi A, glad to see you around. I edited your answer because I couldn't see the result because jQuery isn't loaded, so I used vanilla Javascript, I highly recommend using only vanilla/plain Javascript. Now, what;s the angle all about and the draw direction please?

Comment: hi again D. Your edit looks good. I've been going back and forth between using jQuery or not on SO. Based on your recommendation, I'll probably try to avoid it more often now. In terms of angle: woops, the two reference points need to be symmetrical, i.e. not the start and 1/4 through, but 1/4 through and 3/4 through...making the edit now.

Comment: I have another idea, I think it's gonna blow. I can simplify the path to 4 or 6 lines, this way I can obtain a polygon I can then easily compare points against the first. Of course the damn `8` shape isn't gonna count in this equation, but even so, I should still have something.

Comment: In case my edit doesn't immediately answer your question: I'm finding the 2 ref pts, i.e. 1/4 and 3/4 through the path. In 2 visually identical paths but in opposite "directions" the ref pt coordinates will be identical, but the pt order will be reversed. To detect this, create a vector between the two points and determine its angle in 360 degrees or rather in 2pi (need `atan2` not `atan`). Two paths in the same direction will yield the same angle, while two paths in opposite directions will yield angles that differ by pi (180 degrees).

Comment: My gut reaction is that simplifying the path to 4 or 6 lines won't really add anything to the solution. The solution you started in your question and that I finished is already essentially simplifying the path to 1 line, from the point 1/4 through to the point 3/4 through.

Comment: By the way, an even simpler solution is to just calculate the angle between the starting point and the ending point. The only problem with that is that it won't work on explicitly closed paths, i.e. those paths that explicitly start and end on the same point (as opposed to just using "Z" to indirectly close the path). Thus, while calculating reference points 1/4 and 3/4 through is more expensive, it's probably safer.

Comment: Yes, won't help, all paths are gonna be closed. Still, the idea of angles is used in D3.js in something I've read called `centroid`. I will try it still.

Comment: Also very nice and useful answer! +

Comment: @AndrewWillems my good friend, your solution have finally found its way into a public release, after so loong https://thednp.github.io/kute.js/svgCubicMorph.html